# Trigger - too many rows

Tags: apex, trigger

The following trigger works well in sandbox, is validated in production, but when I used email to salesforce, it returns the following:

> UnexpectedException: MoveAtt: execution of AfterInsert  caused by:
>   System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type
>   (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact
>   salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a
>   filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes
>   null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data
>   skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for
>   instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs
>   many times)  Trigger.MoveAtt: line 9, column 1

Trigger is as follows

```
trigger MoveAtt on Attachment (after insert) {
    List<Id> forDeletionIds = new List<Id>();
    for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
        String parentIdString = String.valueof(a.parentId);
        if (parentIdString.substring(0,3) == '00T'){
            System.debug(a.parentId);
            if(Task.WhoId != null){
                if(Customer_Document__c.Task_ID__c != null){  
                    Customer_Document__c parent = [SELECT Id  FROM Customer_Document__c WHERE Task_ID__c = :a.ParentId Limit 1 ];
                    if (parent.Id  != null){
                        Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
                        Attachment newA = New Attachment(
                            Name = a.Name,
                            Body = body.Body,
                            Description = 'Email Attachment from ' + date.today(),
                            OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
                            ParentId = parent.Id
                            );
                        insert newA;
                        forDeletionIds.add(a.Id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        List<Attachment> forDeletion = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :forDeletionIds];
        delete forDeletion;
    }
}
```

How can I prevent looking for nulls? I don´t know, which Objects causes the 100000 rows.

Comment: The error is happening on line 9 which is: `Customer_Document__c parent = [SELECT Id  FROM Customer_Document__c WHERE Task_ID__c = :a.ParentId Limit 1 ];`. Presumably your production org has more than 100,000 `Customer_Document__c` records in it?

Comment: but didn´t i prevent to look into them all with line 8?

Comment: No, Task is not a Customer_Document__c. It still has to search all the Customer_Document__c records to find the parent Customer_Document__c for the Task.

Comment: so, this would help then?    Customer_Document__c parent = [SELECT Id  FROM Customer_Document__c WHERE Customer_Document__c.Task_ID__c != null and Task_ID__c = :a.ParentId Limit 1 ];

Comment: LIMIT statements have no impact on selectivity.

Comment: i meant the change "WHERE Customer_Document__c.Task_ID__c != null" if this would be of help

Comment: In essence, you first need to find out how many Customer_Document__c records to verify that you have over 100000 rows and you may need to contact Salesforce Support to ask them to index the Task_ID__c field for you if bulkifying your trigger doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: No, the !=null won't help. It still has to search every record for nulls.

Comment: The field Taks_ID__c is indexed now, what is the difference here?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [cheat sheet](http://s3.amazonaws.com/dfc-wiki/en/images/0/0e/Db-query-search-optimization-cheat-sheet.pdf) for a good starting point. If you are querying where `ParentId = null`, your query will not be selective. In your code you guard against `WhoId = null`. Also if `Task_ID__c` is not a lookup field, it will probably not be indexed and your query may be non-selective even if there is only one match.

That said, you should really **move your queries out of for loops**. Pull all your parent ids into a set and query on that. You can then go back and map by `Task_Id__c` for easy retrieval while looping over tasks. This will be easier to accomplish and maintain if you **move your logic out of the trigger body**.

```
static Set<Id> getParentIds(List<Attachment> attachments)
{
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Attachment attachment : attachments) parentIds.add(attachment.ParentId);
    parentIds.remove(null);
    return parentIds;
}

static Map<Id, List<Customer_Document__c>> getDocuments(Set<Id> parentIds)
{
    Map<Id, List<Customer_Document__c>> documents =
        new Map<Id, List<Customer_Document__c>>();
    for (Customer_Document__c document : [
        SELECT Task_ID__c FROM Customer_Document__c
        WHERE Task_ID__c IN :parentIds
    ])
    {
        if (!documents.containsKey(document.Task_ID__c))
            documents.put(document.Task_ID__c, new List<Customer_Document__c>());
        documents.get(document.Task_ID__c).add(document);
    }
    return documents;
}
```

A few other notes.

When you check `Customer_Document__c.Task_ID__c != null` that doesn't do anything for your code. `Customer_Document__c.Task_ID__c` is a `Schema.SObjectField` and is never null.  The same applies to `Task.WhoId`. You want to make sure you are not querying on null, which I outlined above using collections. If you can't bulkify your trigger, you need to check that `a.ParentId != null` instead.

Based on my interpretation of your code, you don't really need to delete any `Attachments`. You are essentially changing two fields, `Description` and `ParentId`. Move this all to a before trigger and then just change those two fields on the `Attachment`

Comment: Adrian, thx for your detailed reply, unfortunately, i am totally new to Apex trigger, doing that by try & fail... your comment sounds logic but i can not realise it that way.

Answer (score -1):

@all

thanks for your comments, i tried the following and it works!

```
trigger MoveAtt on Attachment (after insert) {
List<Id> forDeletionIds = new List<Id>();
for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
String parentIdString = String.valueof(a.parentId);
if (parentIdString.substring(0,3) == '00T'){
    System.debug(a.parentId);
    if(Task.WhoId != null){
        Customer_Document__c parent = [SELECT Id  FROM Customer_Document__c WHERE Customer_Document__c.Task_ID__c != null and Task_ID__c = :a.ParentId Limit 1 ];
    if (parent.Id  != null){
        Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
        Attachment newA = New Attachment(
            Name = a.Name,
            Body = body.Body,
            Description = 'Email Attachment from ' + date.today(),
            OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
            ParentId = parent.Id
        );
        insert newA;
        forDeletionIds.add(a.Id);
    }  }  }
```

List forDeletion = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :forDeletionIds];
delete forDeletion;
    }}